# From SQL Database to Excel with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, odbc, xlsxwriter

I am new to Python. I've successfully connected to my SQL database via an odbc connection and I am pulling data from a table. How do I then get that data into a Excel workbook. Preferably using the xlsxwriter module.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSERVER;PORT=XX;DATABASE=dbname;UID=sa;PWD=##')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from T1 where C2 not like '%text%'")
for row in cursor:
        print row.1, row.2, row3

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` is the easiest bet for this. Here's an example using sqlite as the database backend:

```
In [38]: import pandas as pd

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.092719  0.664147  0.677834  0.605845  0.569223
1  0.656272  0.321661  0.294219  0.818676  0.010610
2  0.041692  0.721683  0.163525  0.175113  0.580234
3  0.852775  0.106076  0.049080  0.649362  0.265763
4  0.481842  0.942276  0.462951  0.386705  0.205302

In [40]: df.to_sql("tbl", sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite"), index=False)

In [41]: new_df = pd.read_sql("select * from tbl", sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite"))

In [42]: new_df
Out[42]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.092719  0.664147  0.677834  0.605845  0.569223
1  0.656272  0.321661  0.294219  0.818676  0.010610
2  0.041692  0.721683  0.163525  0.175113  0.580234
3  0.852775  0.106076  0.049080  0.649362  0.265763
4  0.481842  0.942276  0.462951  0.386705  0.205302

In [43]: new_df.to_excel("out.xlsx")
```

Lines 41 and 43 are the main ones, and this results in a single sheet Excel doc named `out.xlsx` in the current folder.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have your data, it seems like your question is simply how to get your data into Excel. Let's say you have data in an object named `rows`, which is a list of result rows.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('YourResults.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

for row_data in rows:
  worksheet.write(row, col, row_data.1)
  worksheet.write(row, col+1, row_data.2)
  worksheet.write(row, col+2, row_data.3)
  row += 1

workbook.close()
```

This should write rows of data to your spreadsheet. You can view the xlsxwriter tutorial here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html

Just as an aside, you can also access SQL and Excel via ADO (using COM), however, if you're just beginning with Python, that might be a bit more challenging. If you're interested in looking at that later, here's a primer on ADO in python: http://mayukhbose.com/python/ado/index.php

Answer (score 1):

If the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package is available to you, you can easily dump a DataFrame to an Excel spreadsheet. Formatting is also accessible. You'll need to get the data into a DataFrame by appending rows to a list (not sure how pyodbc works). Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
...
for rows in cursor:
    for row in rows:
        data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then dump to Excel.

```
def df_to_excel(path,data_frame):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    data_frame.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='SHEET0')    # sheet 0
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('your_excel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

The first version writes one value (i.e. `row`) in each column sequentially.

```
for index, row in enumerate(cursor):
    worksheet.write(0, index, row)
workbook.close()
```

The second version writes one value (i.e. `row`) in each row sequentially.

```
for index, row in enumerate(cursor):
   worksheet.write(index, 0, row)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Hi when I try to run this I get the following error: TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'pyodbc.Row'> in write()

Comment: Use `row.column` where `column` is the name of the column in your table. So if you have a table with columns `username`, `password` then you will substitute that with the value. The Row object is apparently not supported. The types supported are: `string`, `number`, `formula`, `None`. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write

Answer (score 0):

Using `panda` is the best way.. alternatively may use `openpyxl`
example as below :

```py
# import the nesccesary package
import pyodbc
import openpyxl

# Set connection
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=robbi_database;UID=robbi_username'
                            ';PWD=robbi_password')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create excel
book = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = book.active

# Export data to excell `
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 100 FROM robbi_table ORDER BY editdate DESC")
results = cursor.fetchall()
i = 0
for row in results:
    i += 1
    j = 1
    for col in row:
        cell = sheet.cell(row=i, column=j)
        cell.value = col
        j += 1
# Save to excel and close connection
book.save("myExcelFile.xlsx")
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```